# Unset Read-Only attribute on Certain Directories

Tags: batch-file

I need to find all files in subdirectory starting with a period (e.g. .classpath), and within that directory I need to unset the read-only flag.  Can someone help me finish the 2nd part of this script?  I got the first part - identifying the dirs starting with a period.

Thanks for any help.

```
for /f %f in ('dir c:\time\.*.* /s /a-D /b') do ....for each file do attrib -r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %f in ('dir c:\time\\.\*.* /s /aD /b') do attrib -R %f\\*
```